# Obscure 1980s sci fi animated movie with a woman breaking a man out of a moon-prison cell

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

Trying to find the name of a move I saw (on VHS!) in the late 80s.

I remember the beginning of the movie had a woman who was sent to break a man out of a moon-prison cell (because she wanted him to help her with some quest).  She breaks the guy out and he's not excited to help her but some other guys following the woman attack and he has major fighting skills... and maybe a flying hoverboard?

Comment: Hey there! That's some info already, but could you please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Every little detail you could remember counts :)

Comment: Sounds like the start of MIB3: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCLTAaa3qMM

Comment: @Valorum, MIB is much more recent.

Comment: @o.m. - Indeed. And had I posted it as an answer, I'd have expected to receive downvotes.

Comment: Well... unlikely to be the right answer due to the release date, but there are some similarities with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Leaves